# Is there a way to asynchronously redisplay an element with its original CSS formatting?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example,

```
<html>
<body>
<img id="pic" src="original.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

In Javascript (jQuery):

```
$("#pic").attr("src","newpic.jpg");
```

Now, is there a way to reset `#pic`'s src to `original.jpg` without explicitly setting it as `$("#pic").attr("src","original.jpg");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to reset without reassigning it, since you already changed the DOM.

But if you attach a class using [.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), then you could use .removeClass to reset that.

Comment: Most likely the best sollution.

Comment: *rofl*. Good work on identifying the real point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, is there a way to reset #pic's
>   src to original.jpg without explicitly
>   setting it as

I think NO, you are doing it all in DOM and you can not sort of **undo** your changes. However, you can use variables on top of your script with original defaults and use those variables to reset elements to original values. For example:

```
<script>
var orig_image = 'original.jpg'; // top level variable

$(function(){
  $("#pic").attr("src","newpic.jpg");
});

// later on you show the original one
$('selector').click(function(){
  $("#pic").attr("src",orig_image);
});

</script>
```

Another way is to do with **CSS** classes/IDs and as suggested by S.Mark, you could then use these functions:

```
addClass()
removeClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get all styles, then do whatever you want, and then later get all styles, and then compare the two arrays. Here's something to get you started:

An array of all styles:

```
            var allStyles = ["azimuth","background" ,"backgroundAttachment","backgroundColor","backgroundImage","backgroundPosition","backgroundRepeat","border","borderBottom","borderBottomColor","borderBottomStyle","borderBottomWidth","borderCollapse","borderColor","borderLeft","borderLeftColor","borderLeftStyle","borderLeftWidth","borderRight","borderRightColor","borderRightStyle","borderRightWidth","borderSpacing","borderStyle","borderTop","borderTopColor","borderTopStyle","borderTopWidth","borderWidth","bottom","captionSide","clear","clip","color","content","counterIncrement","counterReset","cssFloat","cue","cueAfter","cueBefore","cursor","direction","display","elevation","emptyCells","font","fontFamily","fontSize","fontSizeAdjust","fontStretch","fontStyle","fontVariant","fontWeight","height","left","letterSpacing","lineHeight","listStyle","listStyleImage","listStylePosition","listStyleType","margin","marginBottom","marginLeft","marginRight","marginTop","markerOffset","marks","maxHeight","maxWidth","minHeight","minWidth","orphans","outline","outlineColor","outlineStyle","outlineWidth","overflow","padding","paddingBottom","paddingLeft","paddingRight","paddingTop","page","pageBreakAfter","pageBreakBefore","pageBreakInside","pause","pauseAfter","pauseBefore","pitch","pitchRange","playDuring","position","quotes","richness","right","size","speak","speakHeader","speakNumeral","speakPunctuation","speechRate","stress","tableLayout","textAlign","textDecoration","textIndent","textShadow","textTransform","top","unicodeBidi","verticalAlign","visibility","voiceFamily","volume","whiteSpace","widows","width","wordSpacing","zIndex"];
```

Here's a jQuery loop that spits out the values after doing a comparison with another's values (in my case, $other was another dom element, but the code's probably similar enough. You will need to edit this slightly:

```
        // Now we loop through each property, and report those defined
        $.each(allStyles, function(key, value){
            if ($this.css(value) !== undefined){
                if (($other.css(value) !== undefined) && ($this.css(value) !== $other.css(value))){
                    $("#jsStylesA").append("<li><span class='property'>"+value+"</span>: <span class='value'>"+$this.css(value)+"</span></li>");
                }
                else {
                    $("#jsStylesB").append("<li><span class='property'>"+value+"</span>: <span class='value'>"+$this.css(value)+"</span></li>");
                }
            }
        });
```

Do you think you can take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
$.extend({
  tempcss: function(prop, val) {
    var props = $(this).data('tempcss') || [];
    props.push([prop, $(this).css(prop)]);
    $(this).css(prop, val);
  },
  revertcss: function() {
    var props = $(this).data('tempcss') || [];
    props.each(function(i, prop) {
      $(this).css(prop[0], prop[1]);
    });
  }
});
```

It will have some edge cases, and obviously your original example isn't a css property. But still.

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use $.data like this

```
$(function() {
    $('body').data('original_image', $('#pic').attr('src'));
    $('#pic').attr('src', 'test.jpg');
});
```

to restore original, read the data :

```
$('#pic').attr('src', $('body').data('original_image'));
```